# Filling datatable to excel sheet in VSTO excel plug in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, vsto

I am creating a excel plug-in in visual studio 2010.
I need to display the data available in a new sheet with name summary.

```
DataTable dt = FillDataTable();          
Excel.Worksheet dtasheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
dtasheet.Name = "Summary";
```

This code i tried inside `Application_WorkbookBeforeSave` event.
On setting the name, the the debug mode closes and shows the excel sheet.
What is the problem here??

Comment: not sure the issue? The code fills a datatable, creates a new Excel sheet and then Names it summary. No where are you populating the sheet with data. Is that what you intended?

Comment: I need to create a new sheet using plug in and add the datatable table data.

Comment: yes but you have no code to add the datatable onto the sheet. What have you tried?